# A Question on Arbitrary Products of Order Topologies.

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of totally ordered set. Assign each $X_i$ with the order topology. Can we define a total order on $\prod\limits_{i\in I} X_i$ so that the induced order topology coincides with the product topology? What if $I$ is countable or finite? I came up with this question when I read chapter 2 in Munkres' *Topology*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual topology on $\mathbb R$ is an order topology, but I don't think the product topology on $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ is an order topology. For one thing, a nontrivial connected linearly ordered topological space can be disconnected by removing one point. The plane can't be disconnected by removing one point.

Comment: In fact, if $X$ is orderable, $\dim(X) \le1$, while $\mathbb{R}^n=n$.

Comment: @bof My bad. This is a satisfying answer, thanks.